# Travel from the UAE to Lithuania by car

Tags: europe, driving, borders, uae, lithuania

I have been traveling around Asia with my family for the past couple of years, and now we are thinking of a plan to get back to Europe.

The idea was to end the journey in Dubai, then fly to Lithuania. However, my friend started talking about [Dubai auction](https://www.emiratesauction.com/en/Cars/OnlineAuction.aspx), where one apparently can get cars at ridiculously cheap prices. The biggest problem and cost is obviously shipping, but this is where being on the ground would be a huge advantage, as I could just pick up the car and be on my way. It would also serve as a great addition to an already awesome trip, as driving by car I could visit/see many more places.

However, I am not sure if it would be possible to drive a car back to Europe (in the end, I would register it in Lithuania most likely), and if possible how [much of a hassle that would be crossing all the borders. I can't get a Google Maps route to go by ferry, but let's pretend that I teleport to Bandar Abbas](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/Vilnius,+Lithuania/Dubai+-+United+Arab+Emirates/@41.3552269,25.2216312,6.29z/data=!4m29!4m28!1m20!1m1!1s0x46dd93fb5c6408f5:0x400d18c70e9dc40!2m2!1d25.2796514!2d54.6871555!3m4!1m2!1d26.0889432!2d44.4509553!3s0x40b1ff556ad4f6a7:0xdf5505ec06b5dc1f!3m4!1m2!1d42.4488329!2d37.2480166!3s0x40096b2f1de30667:0x76c72b7ba8a7f903!3m4!1m2!1d42.1973115!2d32.2873404!3s0x1542e5f646f9498d:0xe8ca163ff5d14913!1m5!1m1!1s0x3e5f43496ad9c645:0xbde66e5084295162!2m2!1d55.2707828!2d25.2048493!3e0)...

I would be crossing (please advise if some of the crossings are a 'bad idea'): UAE (by ferry) -> Iran (transit visa) -> Turkey (visa-free entry for 90 days) -> Bulgaria (EU) -> Romania (EU) -> Hungary (Schengen) -> anything really, as there would be no crossing of hard borders. So far I would [only need a visa for Iran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_European_Union_citizens#Visa_on_arrival).

The trip can take months, I am not limited by time. Is it possible to drive a car bought in Dubai from the UAE to Lithuania?

**EDIT:** [Chat as per Mark's suggestion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80971/dubai-to-lithuania-by-car)

Comment: Google Maps gives a route through Iraq via Moscow to Lithuania, or a route through Syria, via Istanbul and Europe. There are routes, so yes, in theory it's possible but you might not want to take it on. Voting to close as unclear what you're asking, or too broad, or...

Comment: @CannonFodder Hi, added google maps route which shows the countries also I have listed them in question.

Comment: You'd need 1) visas 2) invitations if going through certain countries like Russia, and 3) Carnet de Passage for some countries too  If those are achievable, then yes.

Comment: There are a lot of potential problems here (I'd say they're of the "if you have to ask, then don't do this" variety), but how do you plan to get from Saudi Arabia to Iran without passing through any other countries? If you're serious about pursuing this, consider [a ferry to Iran](https://caravanistan.com/transport/persian-gulf-ferry/bandar-lengeh-dubai/) as your first leg instead.

Comment: @ZachLipton Hi Zach. After couple of years and multiple land crossings in Asia, I have become somewhat more adventurous as I used to be, lol. Ferry sounds like a great idea. Thanks

Comment: Iraq-Turkey path? Unless you drive an armored personnel carrier, please do not attempt that.

Comment: @xuq01 I stand corrected: Iran, my apologies.

Comment: That sounds much better, though you probably would still need to travel through the unstable areas in Turkey...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IF you can get across the Persian Gulf to Iran, and IF you can get the visa, invitations, and other documents you're going to need, I'd not advise the route you're planning. The Iran/Turkey border region is rather unstable. Heck, it's close to a war zone what with the Kurds.

It might be better to plan to go north through Azerbaijan, then all the way through Russia and enter Lithuania from Latvia (thus avoiding Belarus).
Alternatively, if you can't get a visa for Azerbaijan, the route through Armenia and Georgia is also an option.

That region is likely more stable than the route through Turkey.

To avoid most all instability, you'd need to take a longer route through Turkmenistan, Uzbekistan, and Kazakhstan. That's a lot more safe, but also longer and getting visa might be more difficult.

Comment: Hi, I like idea of Armenia and Georgia, no visa required and entry is 180 and 1 year respectively, however I would need Russian visa, which is a downside. Do you have any references in regards Iran Turkey region being unstable I thought they had good relationship.

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius Kurdistan has been unstable for decades, not so much because of tensions between Turkey and Iran but because of separatists fighting against both (but especially against Turkey). This has flared up again due to the Syrian civil war.